# generate c++ include header guards in atom?

Tags: c++, header-files, atom-editor, auto-generate, include-guards

I'm looking for an atom package that generates C++ include guards in .h/.hpp header files. The package should do something like taking an existing C++ header file and surround its contents with appropriate #ifndef #define #endif lines.

If the plugin offers some additional features, like auto-generating cpp and h files from a given class name, that would be great, too.

I'm suprised I couldn't find a sensible plugin by googling for it. Are there any plugins around that match this description?

*Note: This is not a question seeking for opinions (/out-of-topic), but for material to base my further research for such a plugin on.*

Comment: You can create a snippet ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a snippet insted! Opent your `.atom` folders and in the `snippets.cson` file paste this snippet!:

```
'.source.js':
  'guards':
    'prefix': 'hd'
    'body': '#ifndef "${1:*}"\n#define "${1:*}"\n${2}\n#endif'
  'console.error':
    'prefix': 'error'
    'body': 'console.error(${1:"crash"});$2'
```

You will then type `hd`, press tab and start creating a safe header ;)
You can change the prefix anytime by editing the snippet

Comment: There already is a snippet for that - using `def` prefix. It's bundled by default with `language-c` core package.